# java.io.FileNotFoundException: Access denied on Image.IO.write

Tags: image-processing, filenotfoundexception, access-denied

Im cropping 64x128 pixel Images in 4x8 and 8x16 grids and saving them in a Temp Folder to extract features from for image classification. While im doing this in a loop for multiple Images (I crop the first Image, get 8x16 subimages, extract features for each subimage, move to the next image and overwrite the existing subimages) I get an "File not found" Exception at random grid cells because access is denied for said grid cell. This only occurs when working with a big number (say 20+) of Images. How can I work around this ?

My code for the cropping part:

```
package imageProcess;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Crop_Raster {

BufferedImage src;
BufferedImage dst;


public Crop_Raster(BufferedImage src) {
    super();
    this.src = src;
}

public void cropImage_4x8() throws IOException{
    int filenumber = 1;
    for (int y = 0;y<4;y++){
        for (int x = 0; x<8;x++){
            File output = new File("Temp/"+filenumber+".jpg");
            dst = src.getSubimage(16*x,16*y, 16, 16);   
            ImageIO.write(dst, "jpg", output);
            filenumber ++;
        }
    }
}

public void cropImage_8x16() throws IOException{
    int filenumber = 1;
    for (int y = 0;y<8;y++){
        for (int x = 0; x<16;x++){
            File output = new File("Temp/"+filenumber+".jpg");
            dst = src.getSubimage(8*x,8*y, 8, 8);   
            ImageIO.write(dst, "jpg", output);
            filenumber ++;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the following Exception, happening while handling the second subimage of my 6th Training Image:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Temp\2.jpg (Zugriff verweigert)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.stream.FileImageOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.imageio.spi.FileImageOutputStreamSpi.createOutputStreamInstance(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(Unknown Source)
at javax.imageio.ImageIO.write(Unknown Source)
at imageProcess.Crop_Raster.cropImage_8x16(Crop_Raster.java:38)
at svm.CreateVektor.createVector_8x16(CreateVektor.java:94)
at Main_Test.main(Main_Test.java:107)
```

The error occurs during the cropping part, the rest of my methods should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clearing the Temp folder after each Image fixed the issue.